# Callback Method Showing for Service in Android

Tags: android, android-activity, android-service, android-mediaplayer

I am developing background music player service with notification in Android.
While executing code Its showing an error of CallBack Method from Service Class.

Can anyone please help me to solve this error?
Thanks in Advance.

Here is my code of MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NotificationService.Callbacks {
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
Intent serviceIntent;
NotificationService notificationService;
LinearLayout customMediaController;
Button playPauseButton, forwardButton, rewindButton;
SeekBar seekBar;
TextView timer;
ProgressBar loader;
ProgressBar progressBar;
Handler handler = new Handler();
RemoteViews notificationLayout;
PendingIntent pendingIntent;
NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager;
final Integer CALL = 0x2;
TelephonyManager telephonyManager;
PhoneStateListener phoneStateListener;
AudioManager.OnAudioFocusChangeListener onAudioFocusChangeListener;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    startBindService();//start background service to control music while app is running in background
    initialiseAllView();//iniatialise all UI part
    handler.postDelayed(runnable, 1000);//update progress of song
    setNotification();// show controllers in notification bar
    callHandler();//to handle phone calls in between
    audioHandler();// to handle another app playing song in between
}

Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        if (mediaPlayer != null) {
            if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                playPauseButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_pause_circle_outline_black_24dp);
            } else {
                playPauseButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_play_circle_outline_black_24dp);
            }
            updateTimer();
        }
        handler.postDelayed(runnable, 1000);
    }
};
//callback of controllers from notification bar
@Override
public void updateClient(final MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
    this.mediaPlayer = mediaPlayer;
    if (this.mediaPlayer != null) {
        seekBar.setMax(this.mediaPlayer.getDuration());
        this.mediaPlayer.setOnBufferingUpdateListener(new MediaPlayer.OnBufferingUpdateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onBufferingUpdate(MediaPlayer mp, int percent) {
                progressBar.setSecondaryProgress(percent);
            }
        });
        seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                seekMediaPlayer(seekBar);
            }
        });
        mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                mp.seekTo(0);
                mp.start();
            }
        });
    }
}

public void onForwardButtonClick(View view) {
    if (mediaPlayer != null) {
        mediaPlayer.seekTo(mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition() + 2000);
        seekBar.setProgress(mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition() + 2000);
    }
}

public void onRewindButtonClick(View view) {
    if (mediaPlayer != null) {
        mediaPlayer.seekTo(mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition() - 2000);
        seekBar.setProgress(mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition() - 2000);
    }
}

public void onPlayPauseClick(View view) {
    if (mediaPlayer != null) {
        if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
            pauseMusic();
        } else {
            playMusic();
        }
    }
}

public void playMusic() {
    if (mediaPlayer != null) {
        mediaPlayer.start();
        playPauseButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_pause_circle_outline_black_24dp);
        notificationLayout.setImageViewResource(R.id.playnotify, R.drawable.ic_pause_black_24dp);
        updateNotification();
    }
}

public void pauseMusic() {
    if (mediaPlayer != null) {
        mediaPlayer.pause();
        playPauseButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_play_circle_outline_black_24dp);
        notificationLayout.setImageViewResource(R.id.playnotify, R.drawable.ic_play_arrow_black_24dp);
        updateNotification();
    }
}

private void seekMediaPlayer(SeekBar seekBar) {
    mediaPlayer.seekTo(seekBar.getProgress());
}

private ServiceConnection mConnection = new ServiceConnection() {

    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className,
                                   IBinder service) {
        NotificationService.LocalBinder binder = (NotificationService.LocalBinder) service;
        notificationService = binder.getServiceInstance();
        notificationService.registerClient(MainActivity.this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName arg0) {

    }
};

public void startBindService() {
    serviceIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, NotificationService.class);
    serviceIntent.putExtra("Hello","Hello");
    serviceIntent.setAction(Constants.ACTION.STARTFOREGROUND_ACTION);
    startService(serviceIntent);
    bindService(serviceIntent, mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
}

public void initialiseAllView() {
    customMediaController = findViewById(R.id.customMediaController);
    progressBar = findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
    loader=findViewById(R.id.progress);
    playPauseButton = findViewById(R.id.bttn);
    forwardButton = findViewById(R.id.forward);
    rewindButton = findViewById(R.id.rewind);
    timer = findViewById(R.id.timer);
    seekBar = findViewById(R.id.seekBar);
}

public void updateNotification() {
    Notification customNotification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, "notify")
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_music_note_black_24dp)
            .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.DecoratedCustomViewStyle())
            .setCustomContentView(notificationLayout)
            .setOngoing(true)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .build();
    notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(this);
    notificationManager.notify(1, customNotification);
}

public void setNotification() {
    notificationLayout = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(), R.layout.notification);
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    notificationIntent.setAction(Constants.ACTION.MAIN_ACTION);
    notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP
            | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
            notificationIntent, 0);
    Intent playIntent = new Intent(this, NotificationService.class);
    playIntent.setAction(Constants.ACTION.PLAY_ACTION);
    PendingIntent pendingPlayIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0,
            playIntent, 0);
    notificationLayout.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.playnotify, pendingPlayIntent);
    Intent rewindIntent = new Intent(this, NotificationService.class);
    rewindIntent.setAction(Constants.ACTION.PREV_ACTION);
    PendingIntent pendingRewindIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0,
            rewindIntent, 0);
    notificationLayout.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.rewindnotify, pendingRewindIntent);
    Intent forwardIntent = new Intent(this, NotificationService.class);
    forwardIntent.setAction(Constants.ACTION.NEXT_ACTION);
    PendingIntent pendingForwardIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0,
            forwardIntent, 0);
    notificationLayout.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.forwardnotify, pendingForwardIntent);
}

public void callHandler() {
    int permissionGranted = askForPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE, CALL);
    if (permissionGranted == 1) {
        phoneStateListener = new PhoneStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
                if (state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING) {
                    //Incoming call: Pause music
                    pauseMusic();
                } else if (state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE) {
                    //Not in call: Play music
                    if (mediaPlayer != null && !mediaPlayer.isPlaying())
                        playMusic();
                } else if (state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK) {
                    //A call is dialing, active or on hold
                    pauseMusic();
                }
                super.onCallStateChanged(state, incomingNumber);
            }
        };
        telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) this
                .getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        if (telephonyManager != null) {
            telephonyManager.listen(phoneStateListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
        }
    }
}

public void audioHandler() {
    onAudioFocusChangeListener = new AudioManager.OnAudioFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAudioFocusChange(int focusChange) {
            switch (focusChange) {
                case AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS:
                    pauseMusic();
                    break;
                case AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS_TRANSIENT:
                    pauseMusic();
                    break;
            }
        }
    };
    AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) this.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    // Request audio focus for play back
    if (audioManager != null) {
        audioManager.requestAudioFocus(onAudioFocusChangeListener, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN);
    }
}

public void updateTimer() {
    int currentPosition = mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
    if(currentPosition!=0)
    {
        loader.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
    seekBar.setProgress(currentPosition);
    int t = currentPosition / 1000;
    int min = t / 60;
    int sec = t % 60;
    if (min < 10) {
        if (sec < 10) {
            String string = "0" + min + ":0" + sec;
            timer.setText(string);
        } else {
            String string = "0" + min + ":" + sec;
            timer.setText(string);
        }
    }
    if (min >= 10) {
        if (sec < 10) {
            String string = min + ":0" + sec;
            timer.setText(string);
        } else {
            String string = min + ":" + sec;
            timer.setText(string);
        }
    }
}

private int askForPermission(String permission, Integer requestCode) {
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, permission) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // Should we show an explanation?
        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(MainActivity.this, permission)) {
            //This is called if user has denied the permission before
            //In this case I am just asking the permission again
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{permission}, requestCode);
        }
    } else {
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    stopService(serviceIntent);
    if (telephonyManager != null) {
        telephonyManager.listen(phoneStateListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_NONE);
    }

}
```

}

Here is my Code of Service Class :

```
public class NotificationService extends Service {
Callbacks activity;
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
RemoteViews notificationLayout;
NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager;
private final IBinder mBinder = new LocalBinder();
PendingIntent pendingIntent;
String url = "https://www.betezda.com/songs/English/audio/God%20is%20here.mp3"; // your URL here

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return mBinder;
}

//returns the instance of the service
public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
    public NotificationService getServiceInstance() {
        return NotificationService.this;
    }
}

//Here Activity register to the service as Callbacks client
public void registerClient(Activity activity) {
    this.activity = (Callbacks) activity;
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(final Intent intent, final int flags, final int startId) {
    if (mediaPlayer == null) {
        mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        String hello = intent.getExtras().getString("Hello");
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), hello, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.cheshta);
        mediaPlayer.start();

        activity.updateClient(mediaPlayer);

       /* mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
        mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                mediaPlayer.start();
                activity.updateClient(mediaPlayer);
            }
        });
        mediaPlayer.setOnErrorListener(new MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
                return false;
            }
        });*/

        handleNotification(intent);
    } else {
        handleNotification(intent);

    }

    return Service.START_STICKY;
}

private void handleNotification(Intent intent) {
    if (intent.getAction() != null) {
        switch (intent.getAction()) {
            case Constants.ACTION.STARTFOREGROUND_ACTION:
                showNotification();
                break;
            case Constants.ACTION.PLAY_ACTION:
                if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                    mediaPlayer.pause();
                    notificationLayout.setImageViewResource(R.id.playnotify, R.drawable.ic_play_arrow_black_24dp);
                    updateNotification();

                } else {
                    mediaPlayer.start();
                    notificationLayout.setImageViewResource(R.id.playnotify, R.drawable.ic_pause_black_24dp);
                    updateNotification();
                }

                break;
            case Constants.ACTION.PREV_ACTION: {
                int pos = mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
                mediaPlayer.seekTo(pos - 2000);
                break;
            }
            case Constants.ACTION.NEXT_ACTION: {
                int pos = mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
                mediaPlayer.seekTo(pos + 2000);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}

private void showNotification() {
    notificationLayout = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(), R.layout.notification);
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    notificationIntent.setAction(Constants.ACTION.MAIN_ACTION);
    notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP
            | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
            notificationIntent, 0);
    Intent playIntent = new Intent(this, NotificationService.class);
    playIntent.setAction(Constants.ACTION.PLAY_ACTION);
    PendingIntent pendingPlayIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0,
            playIntent, 0);
    notificationLayout.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.playnotify, pendingPlayIntent);
    Intent rewindIntent = new Intent(this, NotificationService.class);
    rewindIntent.setAction(Constants.ACTION.PREV_ACTION);
    PendingIntent pendingRewindIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0,
            rewindIntent, 0);
    notificationLayout.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.rewindnotify, pendingRewindIntent);
    Intent forwardIntent = new Intent(this, NotificationService.class);
    forwardIntent.setAction(Constants.ACTION.NEXT_ACTION);
    PendingIntent pendingForwardIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0,
            forwardIntent, 0);
    notificationLayout.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.forwardnotify, pendingForwardIntent);
    updateNotification();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    notificationManager.cancel(1);
}

public void updateNotification() {
    Notification customNotification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, "notify")
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_music_note_black_24dp)
            .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.DecoratedCustomViewStyle())
            .setCustomContentView(notificationLayout)
            .setOngoing(true)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .build();
    notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(this);
    notificationManager.notify(1, customNotification);
}

public interface Callbacks {
    void updateClient(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer);
}
```

}

And its showing an error

```
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start service NotificationService@870853f with Intent { act=startforeground cmp=newmediaplayer/.NotificationService (has extras) }: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'void NotificationService$Callbacks.updateClient(android.media.MediaPlayer)' on a null object reference
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:3335)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap21(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1578)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6123)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:757)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'void NotificationService$Callbacks.updateClient(android.media.MediaPlayer)' on a null object reference
    at NotificationService.onStartCommand(NotificationService.java:53)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:3318)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap21(ActivityThread.java) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1578) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6123) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:757)
```

Its showing an error of activity.updateClient(mediaPlayer); in Service Class.
Callback method not getting activity.

Answer (score 0):

You should make a null check in your `NotificationService` class's `onStartCommand` method. as your service starts first and then you register your callback to your service. so your `onStartCommand` method get executed on start of your service, there it found your callback, named as `activity`, null. add this line of code in your `onStartCommand`.

```
if(activity!=null)
activity.updateClient(mediaplayer);
```

Comment: Hello, Thanks for your answer. Yes, I tried it but after doing this MainActivity not updating mediaplayer details as activity is showing null. Please help :)

Comment: try to make a static instance of your service class. access it in your activity and get mediaplayer instance.

Answer (score 0):

Move all the code you have in `onStartCommand()` to `registerClient()`. The crash occurs because in `onStartCommand()` the variable `activity` is `null` because `registerClient()` hasn't been called yet. Just delay setting up the `MediaPlayer` stuff until the client actually calls `registerClient()`.

Comment: Please indicate what happened and show what you did. Without details I can't help you.